# How do I go about making an enemy change depending on where the player hit it?

Tags: java, rpg, cocos3d

Currently coding in java, using cocos engine, making a low-poly game with a world which changes based on what the player does, hopefully including the aspect of an enemy changing when the player hits them.

Although I haven't started enemies, I was wondering if it was possible to make parts of them be removed as the battle goes on (like a helmet being broken or something) so that it creates a bit more immersion.

If it isn't possible its totally fine as well, I can always create another idea

Comment: I don't know enough about the engine, but if you can give an enemy multiple hitboxes and have a unique trigger on each of them...

Comment: Would there be a way to go about making it have multiple hitboxes but still work well with many enemies?
I thought multiple hitboxes may cause lag so I was hoping there was a nice alternative...

Comment: If your game has "breakable" objects, a "helmet being broken" could be a Breakable that is also integral to someone's head... Just go for the naïve implementation. Once everything is in place and working, you can retrace your steps and transpose your "hacks" into a generalised solution/system for reuse in your game.

Comment: Ill attempt that, thanks for the help liggiorgio